# set responseType as 'code' in google sign in setting in angular

Tags: angular, google-signin

I am trying to send responseType as 'code' in google sign in API setting.

```
googleInit()
{
    console.log(document.getElementById("googleBtn"));
    gapi.load("auth2", () => {
        this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id:
                "13892768329-54kr4ssbku48jgctclu9b3o7q1h5k3ei.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
            scope: "profile email",
            response_type: "code"
        });
        this.attachSignin(document.getElementById("googleBtn"));
    });
}
```

I was expecting `response_type` as a code since I have given in the setting

but when I open the network in google chrome, I see `response_type:token id_token`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can use 
    response_type = code
only with the gapi.auth2.authorize function and not with gapi.auth2.init 
( see here - > https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/288 )

Also, this means that 
    response_type = code
only works for popups and not redirects.

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question/answer.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*
Also use lists if necessary